# Two different SSD drives, which one to mount for home?

Tags: home-directory, raid, ssd

I've had a 128GB toshiba SSD on my T400 and have just bought a new 240GB intel SSD (335 series). I want to have a clean new dual boot install of ubuntu and windows 7.

With my SATA II system, the new intel SSD should probably be 1.3-1.5 times faster on buffer read and at least twice faster on cached read. Now I need to know which one to mount for my home directory and which one to use for the OS installs.

Option 1) Use faster SSD for windows+linux+home and use the other SSD for extra space.

Option 2) Use faster SSD for windows+linux and mound home on the other SSD.

Option 3) User slower SSD for windows+linux and mount home on the other SSD.

Option 4) Some type of RAID array setup.

Typical programs on linux: Chrome, Thunderbird (heavy), occasional torrent download.
Windows: Starcraft II.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the slower ssd too. Ubuntu boots fast anyway so it really doesn't matter which you choose. You would not notice the difference anyway (unless you do some benchmarks).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the slower SSD for home.  Most of what's stored there are config files and personal files (mp3s,docs,etc).  That leaves the faster to run your OS and applications.  But honestly I doubt an eye test would be able to tell the difference either way.

Comment: My thunderbird makes heavy use of these personal files (many email folder files and index files, etc). I was wondering if having the home on the same drive would be better than keeping it on the old SSD with parallel reads.

Comment: I don't think so.  Like @teddy said, you're probably not going to be able to notice the performance difference without benchmarking.  Another advantage to having home on a separate disk is that you're splitting up the disk I\O from system activities from home activities hence more efficiently using all your I/O capacity. This could be useful especially if you're running VM's.